# is there any open source javascript component can realize the parse and query the RDF data?

Tags: javascript, rdf

is there any open source javascript component can realize the parse and query the RDF data?

now i want to use javascript read and query the RDF file in local client, in server i use Jena. However until now i haven't found a good and efficient one, anybody knows something about this? waiting your suggestions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of pointers:

- [rdfQuery](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/): a Javascript library for RDF-related processing
- [RDF Query in Javascript demo](http://www.w3.org/1999/11/11-WWWProposal/rdfqdemo.html): a W3C demo

I hope this helps.

Comment: so thanks your suggestion. very well. but i am not sure whether rdfQuery can satisfy with saving rdf data as a client file, because my application need working under the offline mode. so i must save the data as a local file and read it when network is off. be spending time learning the rdfQuery, thanks again very much :)

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to use SPARQL to Jena, and ask for JSON results from the SPARQL server.

You can make a SPARQL query using XMLHTTPRequest in javascript. There's an example here: http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/weblog/Comunity%20blog/1653

Comment: so thanks :).  is learning the demo.  the reason of using sparql query under the client is my application need working under the offline mode. so i must save the rdf data(sparql query from the server) as a local client file, then application can read the file and execute the sparql query when the network is broken down. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is another javascript library:

http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/SPARQL_Javascript_Library

Think it is supports RDFj

http://code.google.com/p/backplanejs/wiki/Rdfj

Its worth looking at since both were developed by W3C working group members / invited experts

Comment: So thanks your suggestions. I'm reading and learning the RDFj.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called jOWL that supports OWL Lite (therefore RDF too) and that has widgets for a tree visualisation of hierarchies.:
[jowl](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/)

Comment: so thanks ：） I'm reading and learning ....